# Transition matrix/diagram plotting

Tags: python, graphviz

I am trying to plot the transition diagram for the following 5x5 transition matrix.

```
0.4  0   0  0.6  0
0.2  0  0.4 0.4  0
0.5 0.3  0  0.2  0
0.5 0.3  0   0  0.2
0    0   0   0   1
```

It should plot a transition diagram like this:

[image]

My code below seems to superimpose the transition from 2 to 4 and 4 to 2

```
from graphviz import Digraph

# Create a directed graph
dot = Digraph()

# Set node '1' at the top rank
with dot.subgraph() as s:
    s.attr(rank='source')
    s.node('1')

# Nodes '2', '3', '4', '5' should be on the same level
with dot.subgraph() as s:
    s.attr(rank='same')
    s.node('2')
    s.node('3')
    s.node('4')
    s.node('5')

# Add edges with transition probabilities
dot.edge('1', '1', label='0.4')
dot.edge('2', '1', label='0.2')
dot.edge('2', '3', label='0.4')
dot.edge('2', '4', label='0.4')
dot.edge('3', '1', label='0.5')
dot.edge('3', '2', label='0.3')
dot.edge('3', '4', label='0.2')
dot.edge('4', '1', label='0.5')
dot.edge('4', '2', label='0.3')
dot.edge('4', '5', label='0.2')
dot.edge('5', '5', label='1.0', lhead='3', ltail='3')

# Display the graph inline
display(dot)
```

Transition diagram for my Python code:

[image: Transition diagram for my Python code]

Comment: Your edge definition doesn't match the table you provided. The "1 to 4" edge with weight 0.4 is missing.  The graphic annoyingly has the "2 to 4" and "4 to 2" edges showing on top of each other, but otherwise seems correct once you add the missing edge? What exactly is your problem with it? Just the overlap? Also, where is `display()` coming from? Does your actual code have `dot.view()` perhaps?